# Qiskit SDK problem

Tags: programming, qiskit

So I am getting this error when I fire the command on Ipython or Jupyter Notebook

```
<ipython-input-14-8c9b14139f9d> in< module>()
           from qiskit import IBMQ

ImportError: cannot import name 'IBMQ'
```

Does anyone know that kinda error?
If anyone has experienced such errors while using qiskit, please help here.

Comment: What version of Qiskit do you have installed? Could you make sure that it is at least 0.5?

Comment: @JamesWootton yeah. Okk

Comment: Okkay dude, I have checked and the version is definitely greater than 0.5.

Comment: I actually meant to ask you to check whether you have 0.6, since that is where the IBMQ thing became importable. Also what happens if you simply import qiskit?

Comment: No man, I am unable to import anything.

Comment: Right, good to know (also, I'm guessing that you've installed qiskit). It is probably some confusion on your system between different Python versions, which is quite common (especially on macs). I'll see if I can find a good guide.

Comment: Okkay. Thanks, maybe I can something on github repositories of IBMQ

Comment: Just to let you know, you can circumvent these issues by using a binder image. You can read about it here https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorial/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I faced the same problem. It turned out the problem related to the api some how so use ibmq.delete_accounts to remove all the old api